# Received memory warning. in gallery section Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I am making a handbook table cell in my app and i have 7 pages which each are the images and I'm using uiscrollview with page control but when i run the app it says  Received memory warning.
 and then the app freezes and automatically shuts down, what should i do and this is my code.

```
    @interface HS_HandbookViewController ()
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *pageImages;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *pageViews;

    - (void)loadVisiblePages;
    - (void)loadPage:(NSInteger)page;
    - (void)purgePage:(NSInteger)page;
    @end

    @implementation HS_HandbookViewController
    @synthesize scrollView = _scrollView;
    @synthesize pageControl = _pageControl;

    @synthesize pageImages = _pageImages;
    @synthesize pageViews = _pageViews;

    #pragma mark -

    - (void)loadVisiblePages {
        // First, determine which page is currently visible
CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
NSInteger page = (NSInteger)floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x * 2.0f + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2.0f));

// Update the page control
self.pageControl.currentPage = page;

// Work out which pages we want to load
NSInteger firstPage = page - 1;
NSInteger lastPage = page + 1;

// Purge anything before the first page
for (NSInteger i=0; i<firstPage; i++) {
    [self purgePage:i];
}
for (NSInteger i=firstPage; i<=lastPage; i++) {
    [self loadPage:i];
}
for (NSInteger i=lastPage+1; i<self.pageImages.count; i++) {
    [self purgePage:i];
}
    }

    - (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;

    }



    - (void)loadPage:(NSInteger)page {
if (page < 0 || page >= self.pageImages.count) {
    // If it's outside the range of what we have to display, then do nothing
    return;
}

// Load an individual page, first seeing if we've already loaded it
UIView *pageView = [self.pageViews objectAtIndex:page];
if ((NSNull*)pageView == [NSNull null]) {
    CGRect frame = self.scrollView.bounds;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0.0f;

    UIImageView *newPageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self.pageImages                    objectAtIndex:page]];
    newPageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    newPageView.frame = frame;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:newPageView];
    [self.pageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:newPageView];
}
    }

    - (void)purgePage:(NSInteger)page {
if (page < 0 || page >= self.pageImages.count) {
    // If it's outside the range of what we have to display, then do nothing
    return;
}

// Remove a page from the scroll view and reset the container array
UIView *pageView = [self.pageViews objectAtIndex:page];
if ((NSNull*)pageView != [NSNull null]) {
    [pageView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.pageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:[NSNull null]];
}
    }


    #pragma mark -

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.title = @"Student Handbook";

// Set up the image we want to scroll & zoom and add it to the scroll view
self.pageImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"page 1 handbook.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"page 2 handbook.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"page 3 hand book.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"page 4 handbook.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"page 5 handbook.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"page 6 handbook.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"page 7 handbook.png"],
                   nil];

NSInteger pageCount = self.pageImages.count;

// Set up the page control
self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
self.pageControl.numberOfPages = pageCount;

// Set up the array to hold the views for each page
self.pageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < pageCount; ++i) {
    [self.pageViews addObject:[NSNull null]];
}
    }

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

// Set up the content size of the scroll view
CGSize pagesScrollViewSize = self.scrollView.frame.size;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pagesScrollViewSize.width * self.pageImages.count,         pagesScrollViewSize.height);

// Load the initial set of pages that are on screen
[self loadVisiblePages];
    }

    - (void)viewDidUnload {
[super viewDidUnload];

self.scrollView = nil;
self.pageControl = nil;
self.pageImages = nil;
self.pageViews = nil;
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation                                 {
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    }


    #pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

    - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
// Load the pages which are now on screen
[self loadVisiblePages];
    }

    @end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make sure you have not another apps running ( double tap on home button and flick all running apps to close ). May be images are big and there is not enough memory in your device. If you able to run your app after it try to figure out if you have not memory leaks. Swipe few times and follow your memory.

[image]

If you use ARC than assign nil to your vars since you are not going to use them.